# Kill streak or stun streak? Can I combine them?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I am trying to get The_ INDEPENDENT_hack, and I need to activate 2 kill streaks during 1 sessions. My questions are:

1. Does stun streaks also count (they activate kill streak skill bonus)
2. Can I combine both, kills and stuns? For example kill -> stun -> kill to activate streak?

I am asking because it's kind of hard to notice if I actually got the bonus during my play, as I simply forget about paying attention to it once I am in the middle of massacre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the game is concerned, landing a stun has the same effect as getting a silent kill.  In other words, a single stun will increase a kill streak score (silent or otherwise) by one.

So yes absolutely, stuns count in your kill streaks.  Has been that way since Revelations.

Comment: Kill streak is a bit misleading, it's more of an "attack streak."  For attacks (kills) on contracts or attacks (stuns) on pursuers.